Different result from `fdesetup` from macOS terminal vs Swift app
I'm trying to read and report the FileVault status and other system info from a Mac. If I run the command fdesetup status from a terminal I get the output:
FileVault is On.

However, if I run it from within a SwiftUI app, by using Process, I get a different result:
    let fileVaultStatus = runShellCommand("fdesetup status")

    private func runShellCommand(_ command: String) -> String {
        let task = Process()
        task.launchPath = "/bin/zsh"
        task.arguments = ["-c", command]
        
        let pipe = Pipe()
        let errorPipe = Pipe()
        task.standardOutput = pipe
        task.standardError = errorPipe
        task.launch()
        
        let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
        
        let errorData = errorPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile();
        let errorOut = String(data: errorData, encoding: .utf8) ?? ""
        print(errorOut)
        
        
        task.waitUntilExit()
        
        return output
    }

The result from this is FileVault is Off.
What am I missing here? I would expect a permissions issue to have an error message saying so, so I'm assuming it is not that.

Different scopes, the first command is executed with your account so your access rights and environment settings but the Process command inherits such things from the parent process which is the app itself. Read the documentation for Process

FileVault is a system level setting, so not sure how environment setting would affect it. It seems it can access ‘fdesetup’, it’s just returning the wrong result

Well I did some testing and it turned out I was right :) If I run your code in my app I get the result "FileVault is On" which is the same as I get in the terminal but if I activate App Sandbox for the project and run again I get "FileVault is Off" (which is mentioned in the documentation) so turn of App Sandbox if you want this to work.

Cool, yes the non-sandbox thing works. If you add an answer I'll accept it. Guess I'll open a new question on how to get FileVault status while in a sandbox, because I think an app can't be added to the App Store if sandbox is disabled.

Did you have a look at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicemanagement/fdefilevault? I have no idea if it’s useful myself, I found it while searching online.

That seems to be a API for MDM solutions to push configs to enrolled devices via an MDM server. It doesn't seem to be an API on a user machine just to get the status. I'll try digging a bit more.
